# Vue: La Propiedad id llega vacia

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, vue-router

Actualmente estoy finalizando el curso de **Vue Mastery**, pero la propiedad id me esta llegando vacía cuando tengo que enviarla en la función `EventService.getEvent(this.id)` en el archivo /src/views/EventShow.vue

El mismo lo estoy trayendo de un servidor Json a través de axios, aunque los datos los trae en el EventList en el EventList component no me trae el id

Para ello estoy trabajando con Vuex, Vue Router

Aqui la ruta al repo en github: https://github.com/felloz/real-world-vue

Cualquier ayuda estaría agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He visto que tienes un props (me dí el permiso de quitarlo) y lo que en realidad quieres es pasarle un id por la url por lo que vi en tu router, lo que tendrías que hacer recoger ese id de la url de la siguiente forma:

Ejemplo de tu script de tu vista EventShow.vue:

```
<script>
import EventService from '@/services/EventService.js'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      event: {}
    }
  },
  created() {
    const id = this.$route.params.id;

    EventService.getEvent(id)
      .then(response => {
        this.event = response.data
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('There was an error:', error.response)
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

- this.$route.params.id -> Lo que hace es recoger el parametro llamado id de la url.

Comment: Eso me resolvió el problema, lo extraño es que en el curso está el codigo como lo tengo en el repo y a ellos les funciona, seguro es por un tema de versión.